# Python Regex not catching pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

i am basically scraping data from a particular page.
I have this code:

```
regex = '<ul class="w462">(.*?)</ul>'

opener.open(baseurl)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

... rest of code omitted ...

requestData = urllib2.urlopen(request)
htmlText = requestData.read()

pattern = re.compile(regex)
movies = re.findall(pattern, htmlText)

# Lines below will always returns empty.
if not movies:
    print "List is empty. Printing source instead...", "\n\n"
    print htmlText
else:
    print movies
```

content of htmlText:

```
<ul class="w462">

... bunch of <li>s (the content i want to retrieve).

</ul>
```

htmlText contains the correct source (i tried to ctrl+F it and i can verify that it contains the desired ul element. It just that my regex unable to get the desired content.

I have tried to use this instead:

```
movies = re.findall(r'<ul class="w462">(.*?)</ul>', htmlText)
```

Does anyone know what went wrong?

Comment: Why aren't you using an HTML parser to parse HTML?

Comment: Anyways, your data you seem to find by doing control+F could have been created by some JavaScript, which I don't think regex can catch. (Don't quote me, I could be completely wrong). Consider [selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium). I've never used it, but I think it's the right tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `.` in a regexp matches any character **except for** a newline.  So your regexp can't match anything that spans more than one line (that contains at least one newline).

Change the compilation line to:

```
pattern = re.compile(regex, re.DOTALL)
```

to change the meaning of `.`.  With `re.DOTALL`, `.` will match any character (including newline).

Comment: Ya, for fancy parsing you definitely want a real HTML parsing module, but for simple tasks like this regexps are fine.  Don't heed the haters - LOL ;-)

Comment: Regular expressions are never appropriate in the context of parsing markup languages. NEVER.

Comment: Heh - @username55 was stuck, and is now unstuck.  This was a Python question:  "practicality beats purity" ;-)

Comment: @user2618501 Yes, they can be appropriate at sometimes. If you're dealing with limited HTML, it's fine. Stop being so pedantic over it :p